# Inverse dependencies or, why a package was automatically installed?

Tags: rpm, zypper

On SUSE Tumbleweed, just updated (2023-08-20) and I have seen in the log a package that for sure I've never manually installed

```
...
(343/370) Installing: trainwreck-5.109.0-1.1.x86_64 .......... [done]
...
```

When I used Debian, I was able to satisfy my curiosity using

```
$ apt rdepends trainwreck
trainwreck
Reverse Depends:
  Depends: model-train
$
```

Having googled a little bit, no a substantial bit, the most [relevant find](https://users.suse.com/%7Ekkaempf/Presentations/osc09/visualizing_package_dependencies.pdf)
shows that it can be done, at least for direct dependencies, but is no help in making one, a clueless one like me, understand how the figures were obtained.

How can I obtain at least a list of the reverse dependencies of package `trainwreck` on Suse Tumbleweed?

Answer (score 0):

To find a dependent package in SUSE:

```
zypper se --requires <package>
```

To only search among packages that have been installed:

```
zypper se -i --requires <package>
```